# Count every data that grouped in list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm trying to count total data that grouped in my list.

So here is my code:

```
List<InventoryViewModel> temp =
    InventoriesByLocation.GroupBy(s => s.ProductId).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();
```

I want to count how many `productId` that already groupby().

Comment: MoreLINQ's CountBy may be worth considering - https://markheath.net/post/exploring-morelinq-17-countby .

Comment: So basically you want to count how many unique productId's there is in the list?
`InventoriesByLocation.Select(x => ProductId).Distinct().Count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a sequence of `InventoryViewModels`, where every `InventoryViewModel` has a `ProductId`.

You want to group all `InventoryViewModels` into groups, where every groups contains all `InventoryViewModels` with the same `ProductId`. After that you want to count the number of `InventoryViewModels` in each group, and possibly also some other items. Your example code takes the first element in the group.

```
var groupsWithSameProductId = inventoryViewModels
    .GroupBy(inventoryViewModel => inventoryViewModel.ProductId)
```

Now every group has a `Key`, which contains the `ProductId` that is the same for all elements in your group. The group itself is a sequence of all `InventoryViewModels` that have the `ProductId` equal to the `Key`.

To get the number of `InventoryViewModels` that have this `ProductId`, just `Count()` them. If you want other items, just `Select` them:

```
// continue the LINQ statement
.Select(group => new
{
    ProductId = group.Key,
    NrOfInventroyViewModelsWithThisProductId = group.Count(),

    // only if you want other items:
    FirstInventoryViewModel = group.First(),
    Names = group.Select(groupItem => groupItem.Name).ToList(),
});
```

Note, that every `groupItem` is an `InventoryViewModel` with `ProductId` equal to `group.Key`

There is an [overload of Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__) that combines the grouping and selecting in one statement:

```
var result = inventoryViewModels
    .GroupBy(inventoryViewModel => inventoryViewModel.ProductId,   // make groups with same productId
       (commonProductId, inventoryViewModelsWithThisCommonProductId) => new
       {
            ProductId = commonProductId,
            Count = inventoryViewModelsWithThisCommonProductId.Count(),
            Names = inventoryViewModelsWithThisCommonProductId
                    .Select(inventoryViewModelWithThisCommonProductId.Name)
                    .ToList(),
       });
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation and i get it. but i got 
`Anonymous Type:
     a is new{Guid ProductId,int NrOfInventroyViewModelsWithThisProductId}`
and can i get the same type of list. Or the selected item cant turn into same type of list. In this case: `List<inventoryfiewmodel> mInventories= var result` */selected inventorylist/*??

Comment: I don't know your class `InventoryViewModel`. If it has similar properties, you can use `new InventoryViewModel()`, if it is quite different, then I wonder why you would like to do that. The idea behind object oriented programming is that a dog is different than a cat, so don't try to put a can in a dog object

Comment: `List<InventoryViewModel> InventoriesByLocation = temp.Join(StorageByLocation, i => i.StorageId, s => s.Id, (i, s) => i).Where(i=> i.ExpirationDate<DateTime.Now).GroupBy(s => s.ProductId).Select(g=>new { g.Key,Count=g.Count()}).ToList();` this is my code. Variable temp is `List<inventoryViewModel>` too. I need to put the grouped list to `List<InventoryViewModel>` or put them into variabel that I can access publicly. I can't send var (local variable) to my function.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var count = InventoriesByLocation.GroupBy(s => s.ProductId).Count();
```

Basically, `GroupBy` returns a type roughly equivalent to `IDictionary<int, InventoryViewModel[]>` in your case. So, length of an individual dictionary entry will be the count of a unique `ProductId`.